# how to pause a deployment in k8s?

Tags: kubernetes

I want to test a scenario in which I have to pause the rolling upgrades. Imagine I am having a K8s deployment with 4 pods. These pods were created during helm install command. Then I issue a helm upgrade command. It will perform a rolling upgrade of pods. I want to pause the rolling upgrade at the point where there are two old pods and two new pods exists from my test script.
how can I achieve it ?

Comment: I would try to set `maxUnavailable: 2` and `maxSurge: 2` then monitor when you have 2 pods of each kind and then do `kubectl rollout pause deployment youdeployment`

Answer (score 0):

> I want to pause the rolling upgrade at the point where there are two old pods and two new pods exists. How can I achieve it?

The way to do this in a *controlled* fashion, e.g. for A- and B-testing, is to have two different `Deployments` for the same app. E.g. Deployment `my-app-a` and Deployment `my-app-b`.

How you want to do with incoming traffic, depends on your use case, e.g. 50% to each Deployment.

Comment: i want to pause the rolling upgrade from my test script not manually

Comment: @StarbucksAdmin I updated my wording. By doing it this way, you can _control_ it the way you want, for any purpose.

Comment: actually i dont want to change deployment names.